# JavaScript function scope property - at what point in a closure is it set?

Tags: javascript

The following function returns an object. It's taken from a MDN document.
This object that is returned has properties that are functions, which reference the "private" function changeBy().

I'm pretty sure that the only way an increment() call will resolve the changeBy() function call is to have access to the scope chain - the scope of the enclosing/parent function.

**Q:** Is the scope chain property set on the increment() function where it is declared, even though it is declared inside an object, and has not been invoked at that point?

**Note**
I'm being pointed to [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) as a possible duplicate.

> The magic is that in JavaScript a function reference also has a secret
>   reference to the closure it was created in — similar to how delegates
>   are a method pointer plus a secret reference to an object

**Q:** The **secret** bit is what I'm asking about, which is not explained in the answer given in there. Where is this reference stored?

```js
var makeCounter = function() {
  var privateCounter = 0;
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }
  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    }
  }  
};

var counter1 = makeCounter();
alert(counter1.value()); /* Alerts 0 */
counter1.increment();
alert(counter1.value()); /* Alerts 1 */
```

Comment: At the point that the result object created, `changeBy()` is in scope, so even though it's out of scope where you call `increment()`, `counter1` has its own scope to `changeBy()` (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yes: the fact that the function is declared in an object is irrelevant.

Comment: @Brian, reference to _changeBy_, saved in closure for function assigned to increment field

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no direct reference to changeBy saved. Just the parent scope reference is applied to increment() function, and the changeBy location is only resolved when increment is called. Just need to know how/when that reference is applied to increment(), and what rules govern that i.e. in the case where its declared inside an object, or just declared as a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: increment method refers to makeCounter's changeBy thus the makeCounter scope is not garbage collected after the function exits and remains accessible.

Comment: here nothing specific. Simple closures, so common answer about how closures work should help

Comment: @webduvet From reading the specs, I do not think there is a reference to changeBy function at all. Just a reference to the enclosing parent scope. We might think of it as a saved reference to changeBy(), but I don't think that is how the VM resolves it.

Comment: I concur this is a very standard run-of-the-mill closure. I'm not sure what makes your question special. Are you interested in how the engine implements it? In how the spec defines it?

Comment: I updated the question, with refernece to the possible duplicate. I think what I'm looking for is pretty specific. If I'm wrong, I'm wrong

Comment: *"Where is this reference stored."* – Internally in the Javascript engine. It's not accessible to userland code.

Comment: I found the info I needed in the ECMAScript 5.1 specs and updated the question with that info

Comment: @Brian If you found what you're looking for you should post it as an answer and accept it. If you update your question to contain the answer your question becomes unanswerable which doesn't fit the SO format very well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the level of detail I was looking for in the ECMAScript specs. This is pretty in-depth, but it explains the function creation/initialization process, and the function initialization process when created within an Object Literal

**[ECMAScript 5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)**

**Function Being Created**

When a function is being created, as opposed to called, step 9 covers the scope property:
Where the Lexical Environment is specified by `[[Scope]]`, and `F` is the new Function, and the `Scope` is the current functions scope/lexical environment:

> 9: Set the [[Scope]] internal property of F to the value of Scope

**Entering Function Code** [10.4.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)

> 5. Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of F as the
>      argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.

**Function Created in Object Literal** [11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)

The part I was interested in is *"Pass in the LexicalEnvironment of the running execution context as the Scope"*

> 2. Let closure be the result of creating a new Function object as specified in 13.2 with an empty parameter list and body specified by
>      FunctionBody. Pass in the LexicalEnvironment of the running execution
>      context as the Scope. Pass in true as the Strict flag if the
>      PropertyAssignment is contained in strict code or if its FunctionBody
>      is strict code.

**[ECMAScript 2016](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functioninitialize)**

> Set the [[Environment]] internal slot of F to the value of Scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the scope chain property set on the `increment()` function where it is declared, even though it is declared inside an object, and has not been invoked at that point?

Yes.

`increment` is associated with the lexical environment in which it occurs, and has access to all variables in that environment, even after being "released into the wild" by being returned, whether it's returned directly, or as you are doing, as a value in an object being returned.

> The secret bit is what I'm asking about, which is not explained in the answer given in there. Where is this reference stored?

It's written on a post-in stuck to the refrigerator door. No, seriously, it's stored inside the engine as part of its internal data structures while the JS is being parsed and interpreted.

By the way, you're misusing the term "closure". "Closure" does not simply mean "function", anonymous or otherwise. It refers to a particular interaction and behavior between variables in an outside scope (which are "closed over") and functions defined within that scope which reference them ("close over them").

Comment: Ha. No prob. Do you know what property on the increment function gets set? Is the the [[scope]] value we see when debugging?

Comment: @Brian, yes, you can see closures in chrome devtools in `[[Scopes]]` field, by still no way get it from your js code

Comment: FYI on the term scope chain  - I've seen it a number of times in the MDN reference guide. Scope objects form a chain called the scope chain, similar to the prototype chain used by JavaScript's object system. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript